# Overwritten property in constructor

Tags: javascript

I have one class that extends another, in the inherited class constructor I am overwriting a property also used in the parent's constructor.

```js
class Animal {
  name = "animal";

  constructor() {
    console.log(this.name);
  }
}

class Rabbit extends Animal {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.name = 'rabbit';
  }
}

new Animal(); // shows animal
new Rabbit(); // shows animal
```

Since at the time the parent's constructor is called the new value is not yet available, it shows "animal" again. I know this is due to the JS internals.
The page where I found the problem says that it can be fixed by using methods or getters/setters instead of fields, but I can't find a way to work around it. How can I make it show the new value?

Comment: what i think happes here it's: you call Rabbit constructor -> it calls animal constroctor -> it assign name = animal -> you make the alert -> go back to rabbit constructor and assign 'rabbit' to name. that's why your alert it's wrong

Comment: In this particular case, why not `console.log(this.constructor.name)`?

Comment: Just don't put your `alert` call in the `Animal` constructor if you want it to log the value that's assigned in the `Rabbit` constructor.

Comment: Call the super() after  set New value in Rabbit

Comment: @Adam, that is invalid in JS. `super` must be called before.

Comment: @Bergi I think I can't do it since the parent class must have the same behavior, not just the inherited one. But the solution given is good.

Comment: @limg21 I didn't mean to suggest that you should put the `alert` inside the `Rabbit` constructor, I mean that doing `alert`s (or other side effects) in constructors is a bad idea in general.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add an optional argument to the `constructor`:

```js
class Animal {
  constructor(name = "animal") {
    this.name = name;
    console.log(this.name);
  }
}

class Rabbit extends Animal {
  constructor() {
    super('rabbit');
  }
}

new Animal(); // shows animal
new Rabbit(); // shows rabbit
```

Answer (score 3):

Doing anything in parent constructor with an assumption that it 'knows' anything about classes that extends it is a bad idea, because it leads to close coupling.

A better way to do it is to have a separate function for returning the name:

```js
class Animal {
  name = "animal";

  sayName() {
    console.log(this.name);
  }
}

class Rabbit extends Animal {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.name = 'rabbit';
  }
}

new Animal().sayName(); // shows animal
new Rabbit().sayName(); // shows rabbit
```

Answer (score 1):

The thing you might be confused on is where the value is actually logged.

```js
class Animal {
  name = "animal";

  constructor() {
    console.log('In Animal', this.name);
    //Here it has the value 'animal', Rabbit's constructor hasn't overwritten it yet
  }
}

class Rabbit extends Animal {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.name = 'rabbit';
    console.log('In Rabbit', this.name)
    //rabbit as expected
  }
}

const rabbit = new Rabbit();
console.log('After constructors', rabbit.name) //still rabbit
```

If you look at it after the parent constructor had run, it'll show `rabbit`.

This **is** the expected way in most of the cases, as this prevents the child constructor to mess up the properties before the paren't initialization finishes.

To make the parent receive the child's value anyway (like virtual methods, but for properties), you can use getters (the way you've mentioned):

```js
class Animal {

  constructor() {
    console.log('In Animal', this.name);
    //also rabbit
  }
  get name(){
    return 'animal'
  }
}

class Rabbit extends Animal {
  constructor() {
    super();
    console.log('In Rabbit', this.name)
    //rabbi
  }
  get name(){
    return 'rabbit'
  }
}

const rabbit = new Rabbit();
console.log('After constructors', rabbit.name) //rabbit
```